# :{ AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'config' in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, config, attributeerror, tkinter-canvas

That's my code and I have a proplem with config() method it dosen't work with me when I use it with canvas it give me this error:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'config'
so please help me because I stuck here....

````
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.title('3R')
root.geometry('350x300')
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

myCanvas = Canvas(root, width=350, height=300)
myCanvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

#File location
Folder_Name =""
def openLocation():
    global Folder_Name
    Folder_Name = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if(len(Folder_Name))>1:
        LocError.config(text=Folder_Name, fg='green')
    else:
        LocError.config(text='Please Choose Folder!!',fg = 'red')
LocError = myCanvas.create_text(175,120, text='You must select a location',fill='red', font=('jost', 10))
#Button for location
SaveLoc = Button(root, text='Choose Path', command = openLocation)
myCanvas.create_window(130,87, anchor='nw', window=SaveLoc)

root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: `<tkinter.Canvas>.create_text` returns an int that is the identifier for that sprite. It isn't a tkinter widget so it doesn't have the `config` method. I will write an answer with the corrected code in 1 sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your `if` statement as follows:

```
if len(Folder_Name) > 1:
    myCanvas.itemconfig(LocError,text=Folder_Name, fill='green')
else:
    myCanvas.itemconfig(LocError,text='Please Choose Folder!!',fill='red')
```

`itemconfig` takes an id or tag of the canvas item and edits the properties of it.  Also there is no `fg` option for `text` of canvas, so change that to `fill`.

Comment: Yes, I already tried it but still give me an Error. Thank you.

Comment: oops, I was trying the code with itemconfig() all the day but it doesn't work. However, its work now

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.title("3R")
root.geometry("350x300")
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

myCanvas = Canvas(root, width=350, height=300)
myCanvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

#File location
Folder_Name = ""
def openLocation():
    global Folder_Name, myCanvas, LocError
    Folder_Name = filedialog.askdirectory()
    myCanvas.delete(LocError) # Delete the old sprite
    if len(Folder_Name) > 1:
        # Create a new sprite with the correct parameters:
        LocError = myCanvas.create_text(175, 120, text=Folder_Name, fill="green", font=("jost", 10))
    else:
        # Create a new sprite with the correct parameters:
        LocError = myCanvas.create_text(175, 120, text="Please Choose Folder!!", fill="red", font=("jost", 10))
LocError = myCanvas.create_text(175, 120, text="You must select a location", fill="red", font=("jost", 10))
#Button for location
SaveLoc = Button(root, text="Choose Path", command=openLocation)
myCanvas.create_window(130, 87, anchor="nw", window=SaveLoc)

root.mainloop()
```

The variable `LocError` is an int. It is used to identify the sprite (for the text). To change it, I deleted it and created a new one with the correct text/fill.

Comment: Why are you creating a new canvas item, you can use `itemconfig()`.

Comment: You are creating a new canvas item each time, why bother when you have a method to do the same thing explicitly.

Comment: If I had to guess internally it does the same thing, destroy the old sprite and create a new sprite. Even if my method is slower the difference wouldn't be noticeable.

Comment: It will be noticible over time, as the canvas has a limit to the number of items it can create. Element identifiers aren't ever reused, and eventually, the identifiers will get too large.

Comment: How many sprites will that be? I have had more than 1000 sprites without a problem - badly designed code.